# Keras ImageDataGenerator flow training results and .evaluate() results with train data result very different

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm not sure is there something wrong with mycode or something wrong with keras.
But if I use **same** dataset for training and testing I got totally different result when using batches (ImageDataGenerator flow).
I even logged after every epochs the evaluating result, and these are completely different and doesn't seem to go better over the time.

So my question is, is there something wrong in the code that causes this or is there a bug in Keras/tensorflow side?

Tested versions:

- Keras 3.0.4, tensorflow 2.15.0
- Keras 2.14.0, tensorflow 2.14.0

The code:

```py
import math
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import Callback

class LossAndErrorPrintingCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self, train_images, train_labels):
        super().__init__()
        self.train_images = train_images
        self.train_labels = train_labels

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        train_loss, train_acc = self.model.evaluate(self.train_images, self.train_labels, verbose=0)
        print(f'  For epoch {epoch}, train_loss: {train_loss}, train_acc: {train_acc}')


def load_and_preprocess_data():
    # Load data
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

    # Preprocess data
    train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28, 28, 1))
    train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255

    test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28, 28, 1))
    test_images = test_images.astype('float32') / 255

    # Prepare labels
    train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
    test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

    return train_images, train_labels, test_images, test_labels        

def create_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model

def train_model_without_batches(model, train_images, train_labels, epochs, batch_size):
    model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,
               callbacks=[LossAndErrorPrintingCallback(train_images, train_labels)])

def train_model_with_batches(model, train_images, train_labels, epochs, batch_size):
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    steps_per_epoch = math.ceil(len(train_images) / batch_size)
    model.fit(datagen.flow(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=batch_size),
          steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=epochs,
          callbacks=[LossAndErrorPrintingCallback(train_images, train_labels)])

def evaluate_model(model, train_images, train_labels, test_images, test_labels):
    # Evaluate model
    train_loss, train_acc = model.evaluate(train_images, train_labels)
    print(f'Train loss: {train_loss} and train accuracy: {train_acc}')

def main():
    epohcs = 5
    batch_size = 128

    train_images, train_labels, test_images, test_labels = load_and_preprocess_data()
    model = create_model()

    # Select way to train the model with batches or without batches
    #train_model_without_batches(model, train_images, train_labels, epohcs, batch_size)
    train_model_with_batches(model, train_images, train_labels, epohcs, batch_size)

    evaluate_model(model, train_images, train_labels, test_images, test_labels)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Results when running without batches (training and evaluating results are similar and this expected result):

```
Epoch 1/5
458/469 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2670 - accuracy: 0.9235  For epoch 0, train_loss: 0.12449653446674347, train_acc: 0.9648666381835938
469/469 [==============================] - 6s 11ms/step - loss: 0.2646 - accuracy: 0.9240
Epoch 2/5
466/469 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1092 - accuracy: 0.9685  For epoch 1, train_loss: 0.07848010957241058, train_acc: 0.9773666858673096
469/469 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.1089 - accuracy: 0.9685
Epoch 3/5
462/469 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0716 - accuracy: 0.9787  For epoch 2, train_loss: 0.0506039522588253, train_acc: 0.9850333333015442
469/469 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.0714 - accuracy: 0.9787
Epoch 4/5
467/469 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0526 - accuracy: 0.9842  For epoch 3, train_loss: 0.04015552997589111, train_acc: 0.9885333180427551
469/469 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.0525 - accuracy: 0.9842
Epoch 5/5
467/469 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0394 - accuracy: 0.9882  For epoch 4, train_loss: 0.028549131006002426, train_acc: 0.9918333292007446
469/469 [==============================] - 6s 12ms/step - loss: 0.0393 - accuracy: 0.9883
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0285 - accuracy: 0.9918
Train loss: 0.028549131006002426 and train accuracy: 0.9918333292007446
```

If using with batches function then train results and evaluated results are totally different (especially the loss function):

```
Epoch 1/5
464/469 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.2347 - accuracy: 0.2723  For epoch 0, train_loss: 18.376285552978516, train_acc: 0.3831000030040741
469/469 [==============================] - 6s 12ms/step - loss: 2.2329 - accuracy: 0.2745
Epoch 2/5
468/469 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6610 - accuracy: 0.5924  For epoch 1, train_loss: 51.76939010620117, train_acc: 0.5129333138465881
469/469 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 1.6604 - accuracy: 0.5925
Epoch 3/5
460/469 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0350 - accuracy: 0.7518  For epoch 2, train_loss: 44.368038177490234, train_acc: 0.6714166402816772
469/469 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 1.0312 - accuracy: 0.7527
Epoch 4/5
462/469 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.7381 - accuracy: 0.8142  For epoch 3, train_loss: 43.24611282348633, train_acc: 0.7215333580970764
469/469 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.7365 - accuracy: 0.8145
Epoch 5/5
465/469 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5944 - accuracy: 0.8442  For epoch 4, train_loss: 47.87458419799805, train_acc: 0.7287333607673645
469/469 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 0.5943 - accuracy: 0.8441
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 47.8746 - accuracy: 0.7287
Train loss: 47.87458419799805 and train accuracy: 0.7287333607673645
```